# Jquery with Json response is showing extra values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JQUERY Question.

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'json',
        url:'/bin/getpath',
        success: function(jsonArray){
            for(var i in jsonArray) {
                $("#myselect").append("<input type='radio' name='path'   value='"+jsonArray[i]+"'> "+jsonArray[i]+"</input><br/>");
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id ="myselect"></div>
```

And JSON RESPONSE from this URL is :

[image]

When i am running this code, its working fine in firefox although same code is showing one more radio button as below. Please help :

[image]

Regards,
TD

Comment: Get rid of the `</input>`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion ! Just realized that it was not needed, but that doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: Looks like some of your code is extending `Array.prototype`, most likely to polyfill `find`. `for/in` iterates over **all** enumerable properties of the object. An easy solution would be to use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: That kind of thing can mess up a page! Also, you are using `for..in` which is for listing object properties.

Comment: Thanks guys ! I changed the loop from for and its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Below is working code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url:'/bin/getpath',
    success: function(jsonArray){
        $.each(jsonArray,function(index,value){
            $("#myselect").append("<input type='radio' name='path' value='"+value+"'> "+value+"<br/>");
        });
    }
});
```